# Set command can't handle lines constituting of a \n (word/line counting script)

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have a problem with execution of a while loop, I have found out that the problem  involves the execution of the set command, the assigment of the \n character to an environmental variable constitutes a problem. Why does it happen and how to solve it?

my code is:

```
echo "Enter a filename:\c"
read fname
terminal=`tty`
exec < $fname
nol=0   
now=0       
while read line
do      
    nol=`expr $nol + 1`
    set $line
    now=`expr $now + $#`
done
echo "Number of lines:$nol"
echo "Number of words:$now"
exec < $terminal
```

When it encounters a line with nothing but a newline character in it, it prints system data and all of the variables:

```
CINNAMON_VERSION='1.8.8'
COLORTERM='gnome-terminal'
(...)
fname='drunk'
line=''
nol='19'
now='137'
terminal='/dev/pts/0'
```

(...) indicates omission of an entire block of system data

Comment: Use `set -- $line`

Comment: @edwin: Thanks, it works :) Can you please explain, how does it work? How does "--" change the way set processes the input?

Comment: The `--` tells `set` that what follows are the positional parameters. Read `help set`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I don't know what idea did I have behind asking about a general parameter, instead of reading up on the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
set $line
```

use

```
set -- $line
```

Read `help set` to see why this works.